# Conditional Interpolation Excel

Tags: excel

I have the following excel setup that is extremely massive but here is a simplified setup:

```
Site1 X-Given   Y-Given Site2   X-New-Given Y-Interpolated
A     10        400     A       25      550
A     20        500     A       25      550
A     30        600     A       26      560
A     40        700     B       27      570
A     50        800     B       30      600
B     10        400     B       15      450
B     20        500     B       25      550
B     30        600     B       30      600
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have each Y-Interpolated only interpolate based upon its specific site and not have any cross over. So site A would only interpolate with site A, and same with site B... so on and so forth.

I'm using the interpolate excel addin which has the following syntax:
=interpolate(x_array,y_array,x_given)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you post the code for the add in?
That way we could discuss how to modify it.

Because it isn't a native excel function we wont be able to approach adding If statements into it by making it an array formula.

Comment: how about use filtering to break your data sets into two, 1 for Site1 = A, Site2 = A and 1 for Site1 = B, Site2 = B (or however you want it to match), then run the interpolate function on each data set?

Comment: @Gimp - I posted the interpolates syntax if that's what you were refering to? =interpolate(x_array,y_array,x_given)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - I thought about that, and ideally I would have it just be a single formula but that may have to be my next option. I wanted to avoid it as I have ~100,000 items to interpolate!

Comment: To @Gimp's point, if this is from a custom add-in that someone built (i.e- not a standard Excel Add-In), you should be able to find the VBA code behind the UDF (user-defined function) interpolate. I didn't see this formula inside of any Excel standard add-ins, so chances are it's a custom one. To find the code, click Alt + F11 to open the VBE. Do a search for interpolate and see if you find something that says `Function interpolate(...)` If so, post the code  for that function and we can then adjust it to help you get what you want.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman that's correct.
@EricEscobar If you'd like the function modified we'd have to rewrite your Interpolate function, or create a new one that was basically `=interpolate(x_array,y_array,x_given,condition_array, condition)` where the condition_array array would be your site1 column, and the condition would be the current row's site.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman

Sorry I looked all throughout the VBE and found nothing, this is the add-in website that I've been using.

http://www.xlxtrfun.com/XlXtrFun/XlXtrFun.htm

Comment: Eric, make sure you look through all the projects (see `Project Window`) in the VBE. Your Add-In is in a separate project than your the Workbook you have open. Either that, or edit your post with a link to the workbook you are using, so we can find it easily.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I browsed the website and found that the functions he is using were compiled into an xll file called 'XlXtrFun.xll' because it's been compiled into an xll there is not an easy way to view the 'VBA' code.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this worksheet function alternative... with data in `A1:E9`, enter this in `F2` and fill down:

```
=FORECAST(E2,IF(MMULT(ROW(B$2:B$9)-LOOKUP(0,(B$2:B$9>=E2)/(A$2:A$9=D2),ROW(B$2:B$9))-0.5,1)^2<1,C$2:C$9),B$2:B$9)
```

*Update*: Here's a slightly shorter alternative entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

```
=PERCENTILE(IF(A$2:A$9=D2,C$2:C$9),PERCENTRANK(IF(A$2:A$9=D2,B$2:B$9),E2,20))
```

This assumes a positive relationship between variables and returns values at both boundaries.

**Background**

If you're going to use worksheet functions for this, the obvious approach is to find the neighboring two points to X: (X1,Y1) and (X2,Y2). Then calculate Y using:

```
Y = Y1 + (X - X1) * (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1)
```

The problem is that this leads to a lengthy formula involving six INDEX/MATCH combinations and six more conditions for restricting data to the specified site. This leads one to look for other options...

**1**. The first formula looks complicated but all it's doing is applying a straight line fit based on the two neighboring points for the same site. Evaluating the formula for the third row above - by highlighting each part of the formula and pressing F9 - gives:

```
=FORECAST(26,{FALSE;500;600;FALSE;...},{10;20;30;40;...})
```

FORECAST ignores non-numeric data so the result is the same as just using {500,600} and {20,30} for the 2nd and 3rd arguments. You can use F9 on other parts of the formula to break it down further - I'll leave details to you. (The MMULT(...,1) part just changes the argument to an array so you can enter the formula without array-entry.)

**2**. The second formula is easier to follow. First note that in Excel percentiles are calculated by linear interpolation and the IF part is just restricting the numeric data to the specified site. Assuming data is increasing it follows that we can find the k-value in the PERCENTILE formula that matches the lookup value in the x-range and return the y-range value with that k-value. For the example in question:

```
26  =PERCENTILE({10,20,30,40,50},0.4)
560 =PERCENTILE({400,500,600,700,800},0.4)
```

To calculate the value of 0.4 the PERCENTRANK can be used which is inverse to PERCENTILE:

```
0.4 =PERCENTRANK({10,20,30,40,50},26)
0.4 =PERCENTRANK({400,500,600,700,800},560)
```

The formula above follows by combining these two functions, the last argument is set to 20 for full precision (Excel stores values internally to around 15-17 digits of precision).

Comment: Made a couple of amendments and added explanation above. You might be able to use the `IF(A$2:A$9=E2` condition in your XLL function too, you would need to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Because the tool that you're using is based on a .xll add in for excel, you(or we) can not modify the code or create a custom version of `interpolate` that allows adding conditions.

Instead, you'll have to filter your data apart and then run the custom-function on the filtered datasets.